# Is there an easy way to add permissions to a user or a group in Django?

Tags: python, django, permissions, authentication

I'm currently adding permissions to users and groups like this:

```
permissions = list(
  Permission.objects.filter(
    Q(codename='add_server', content_type=ContentType.objects.get(app_label='bildverteiler', name='server'))
    | Q(codename='change_server', content_type=ContentType.objects.get(app_label='bildverteiler', name='server'))
    | Q(codename='delete_server', content_type=ContentType.objects.get(app_label='bildverteiler', name='server'))
    | Q(codename='change_group', content_type=ContentType.objects.get(app_label='bildverteiler', name='group'))
    | Q(codename='add_group', content_type=ContentType.objects.get(app_label='bildverteiler', name='group'))
    | Q(codename='delete_group', content_type=ContentType.objects.get(app_label='bildverteiler', name='group'))
    | Q(codename='change_user', content_type=ContentType.objects.get(app_label='auth', name='user'))
    | Q(codename='add_user', content_type=ContentType.objects.get(app_label='auth', name='user'))
    | Q(codename='delete_user', content_type=ContentType.objects.get(app_label='auth', name='user'))
  )
)
some_user_obj.user_permissions = permissions
```

Is there a better way ? Maybe without the query ?

Answer (score 3):

This solution has less characters:

```
query=Q()
for app_labe, name in [
  ('bildverteiler', 'server'),
  ('bildverteiler', 'group'),
  ('auth', 'user')]:
   query|=Q(content_type__app_label=app_label, content_type__name=name, codname__in=['%s_%s' % (perm_name, name) for perm_name in ['change', 'add', delete'])

Permission.objects.filter(query)
```